# When apps like CI/CD require your github access token, how do they store it securely?

Tags: access-token

I'm facing a similar situation where I need to store users' access tokens, but I'm not sure how to securely store them in the server.

I've only ever used a security manager for my tokens, and salt hashing passwords but I need to decrypt the access token so I can use it on behalf of the user.